# Static blocks and Field.get(null) with static not primitive data fields

Tags: java, reflection, static

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {

    static {
        B.load(A.class);
    }

    public static final C field1 = new C("key1", "value1");

    public static final C field2 = new C("key2", "value2");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.field1);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class B {

    public static void load(Class<?> clazz) {
        for (Field field : clazz.getFields()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("B.load -> field is " + field.get(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public class C {

    private final String key;

    private final String value;

    public C(String key, String value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C [key=" + this.key + ", value=" + this.value + "]";
    }

}
```

When A is executed I get:

```
B.load -> field is null
B.load -> field is null
C [key=key1, value=value1]
```

Why does field.get(null) return a null value when it is executed? I get no exception and it seems that this behavior is not explained by the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all static members will be executed (for static blocks) and initialized (for static fields) in declaration order. Try placing the static block of class `A` at the end of the class, or at least after the static fields. Lemme know if that makes a difference.

EDIT: info regarding the behaviour for primitives and Strings...

When you have a final static field that is a primitive or a String literal (or an expression that can be statically evaluated that results in one of these), it's considered a compile-time constant. Basically, setting such a value does not require "computation", like invoking a constructor or evaluating vis-a-vis other fields that may not have been initialized yet. Although Strings aren't primitives, they're given a special treatment in compilation to make String literals in code a possibility.

This means such fields can be assigned as soon as a class has been loaded and is ready for initialization. Although I don't know the specification details regarding that, experimenting with reflection shows that this is what must be happening.

Following sections of the Java language specification are relevant to understanding this behaviour:

- [Restrictions on the use of fields during initialization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2.3). Reflection lets you get to these fields "sooner" than they appear in source code order. If you tried using them directly in a static block that appears before the field declaration you'd get an error regarding an illegal forward reference from the compiler.
- [Initialization of classes and interfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4).
- [What constitutes a constant expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28).
- [Final variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.4). That last paragraph of this section is quite relevant and implies more than its vagueness lets on.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue but there is still something I don't understand. Why the issue does not appear if I use a primitive data type instead of C (e.g. static int field1 = 1 and static int field2 = 2 with the static block containing B.load declared before the fields)?

Answer (score 1):

In your class A you have to declare the static fields **before** the call to your static function.

```
public static final C field1 = new C("key1", "value1");

public static final C field2 = new C("key2", "value2");

static {
    B.load(A.class);
}
```

The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) explains it:

`A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.`